# What takes up less memory when allocating: UIView or UILabel?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

What takes up less memory when allocating:  UIView or UILabel?

thanks

Comment: Does it _really_ matter?

Comment: This question is nonsense when you consider that each one does an entirely different thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the most abstract sense, [UILabel](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html) would take more memory since it inherits from [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIView).

But it really depends on what you're doing. I highly recommend that you do *not* attempt to replicate UILabel's functionality in a UIView. Since you do not appear to have an intimate understanding of the inner-workings of the UIKit framework, you would be doing it more inefficiently than the Apple engineers have.

Use what fits; what is easiest, and what works. It'll save you a lot more work in the long-run, especially if you write code that works well only with a certain implementation and then they end up changing implementations, etc.

Comment: He would simply have to forgo the use of text labels in his app's UI if he's that desperate to save memory.